# How to convert StreamReader to double

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a streamreader from an external html document:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/version.html");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

double current = double.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());

if (current >= 10.5)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

But it throws an exception `(0xc0000005) 'Access violation'`

Contents of the html: `0.10.5`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Changed double to version as suggested:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/version.html");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

Version current = Version.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());

if (current >= 0.10.5)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Still the same exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The program '[6344] APP.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6344] APP.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

Comment: What line exactly does the error occur on? (Also "0.10.5" isn't a valid double, you can't have two decimal points, but that shouldn't cause an error like that.)

Comment: `A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The program '[2604] APP.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2604] APP.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

Comment: You should've posted all of that at first, since now I can see the *actual* error is just a `FormatException`.

Comment: Stream reader can return null chars or header values (encoding or something else) of the stream.. So first filter your stream data to your exact needs and then use double.TryParse() method

Comment: That code can't be correct, you have a lowercase `version`.  Please always copy and paste your *exact* code.  Also, use an intermediate string for the result of `reader.ReadToEnd()`, and print it out, so you can be sure of what you're getting. Don't assume anything.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart "0.10.5" is what I get if printed directly.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd be getting a `(0xc0000005) 'Access violation'`. Are you running this program in a normal way, under the Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes. I'm Running it like that.

Comment: @JoseCardama Are you able to post the real URL you are accessing?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart http://m1.beatpad.net/version.html

Answer (score 2):

If the number you are parsing is a version, perhaps you should consider the [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Version.aspx) class, instead of `double`.

Call [`Version.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.parse.aspx) on your string.

It also works as expected for comparing versions.

```
Version v1 = Version.Parse("0.10.5");
Version v2 = Version.Parse("0.11.2");

Console.WriteLine("v2 > v1 = {0}", v2 > v1);      // Outputs True
Console.WriteLine("v2 < v1 = {0}", v2 < v1);      // Outputs False
```

---

I'm not sure what your issue is. The following code worked just fine for me (in a [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) 4 session)

```
void Main()
{
    string url = "http://m1.beatpad.net/version.html";
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    var response = request.GetResponse();

    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var ver = Version.Parse(data);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ver);
}
```